# What is the mechanical mechanism of Dermapen?

Tags: mechanisms

I need a mechanism that converts rotational motion to a reciprocating mechanism at a horizontal line using a dc motor.

By 'horizontal line', I mean the motor and the reciprocating part are in the same line not like a Scotch Yoke.

Dermapen uses this mechanism all component in same horizontal line and the needle go forth and back.

What is this mechanism?

Comment: "you need a mechanism" or you want to know what Dermapen uses?

Comment: mechanism only....

Comment: look at swash plates, create reciprocal motion, same axis as motor.

Comment: You can do this motion with a cam mechanism (for shorter strokes), screw mechanism or you can just swap to electric cylinders

Comment: What is Dermapen?